# How to create table in bootstrp that on mobile view will not be scrollable on x axis but will still be visible?l

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a table using bootstrap, and put it in a div of class container-fluid. On a desktop view it looks like this:
[image]

In my CSS I used @media in order to determine certain width under which my container-fluid will take 100% of the screen, but still on mobile view, part of the right side of the table is hidden, and I have to horizontally scroll in order to see it. It looks like this:

[image]

My relevant html code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="tableCont">

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                <th title="Quantity of the product" scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Tomato </td>
                <td><input type="number" min="1" max="50"></td>
                <td><button title="Include product in list">Include</button></td>
                <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Potato</td>
                <td><input type="number" min="1" max="50"></td>
                <td><button title="Include product in list">Include</button></td>
                <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
```

My relevant CSS is:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
#tableCont {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: white;
  width: 68%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #tableCont {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

How can I set the mobile view so the whole width of the table will be visible with no horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @atoms Yes, but then the columns become too dense on desktop view

Comment: try removing the `tableCont` css

Answer (score 0):

Try changing width to max-width in media query.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #tableCont {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

put this in your head tag Html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and on your CSS:

```
.table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

and if you want your content to start from the left side and still fit the screen put this code in #tableCont:

```
#tableCont {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

you can solve this problem with CSS grid as well, so if that interests you
visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: @Ori Lev This should work as per your requirement, hope that helps.